# How do we efficiently compute the value of expression given below?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, gcd-and-lcm, dynamic-programming

How to compute the value of following expression efficiently?

$$\sum_{x=1}^N\sum_{y=1}^N \frac{xy}{\gcd(x,y)^2}$$

I tried by my self but I am getting TLE with my solution.

Problem from [HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/november-circuits-19/algorithm/delta-a6f44e8a/).

Comment: This is a good place to start learning writing the right notations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thanks @Steven31415, I will use this notes for further question

Comment: so an LCM problem.

Comment: *“I am getting TLE (time limit exceeded)”* – so this is from some contest/competition?

Comment: yes, it's one of the contest problem.

Comment: Is it a public contest? Can you add a link to the problem description? Is the contest still active? (There are certain policies here to avoid cheating, compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774/42969.)

Comment: yes, its a public contest and the question has been asked on HackerEarth(https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/november-circuits-19/algorithm/delta-a6f44e8a/)

Comment: A related question: [Summation of greatest common divisor: $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3443650).

Answer (score 1):

You can halve your computations by noticing the sum is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ so that:

$$S=N+2\sum_{1\le x<y\le N}\frac{xy}{\gcd(x,y)^2}$$

Since you have the [dynamic-programming](/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming) tag, I'll also mention that the $\gcd$ can be computed dynamically. It suffices to use

$$\gcd(x,y)=\begin{cases}x,&x=y\\\gcd(y,x),&x>y\\\gcd(x,y-x),&x<y\end{cases}$$

or the usual $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(y,x\%y)$. By caching the results here, a lot of recomputation can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

below is my solution for the problem. but I am getting TLE in some of the test cases. could anyone help me on this to improve the complexity?

## include

## define ll long long

using namespace std;

const unsigned ll MOD = 1000000007;

ll gcd(ll a, ll b) {

```
if(b == 0){
    return a;
}
return gcd(b, a%b);
```

}

ll compute(ll n) {

```
ll ans =0;
for(ll i =1; i <= n; i++) {
    for(ll j =i; j <= n; j++) {
        ll g =0, lm =0, r =0;
        g = gcd(i, j);
        r = (i*j)/(g*g);
        if(i == j) {
           ans = (ans+r)%MOD; 
        } else {
            ans = (ans+2*r)%MOD;
        }
        ans %= MOD;
    }
}
return ans;
```

}

int main() {

```
ll n;
cin>>n;
ll ans = compute(n);
cout<<ans<<endl;
return 0;
```

}