# Summation of greatest common divisor: $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, approximation, gcd-and-lcm

$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{GCD(i,j)^2}$

I stuck with this summation equation trying to simplify. First I thought is equal to lcm(i,j) but that doesn't solve it.
I have till now solved summation with only one variable like n.
But how to tackle problem like this.

Comment: [The sequence,](http://oeis.org/A064951) for reference.

Comment: Could you see that $ij=\gcd(i,j)\text{lcm}(i,j)$?

Comment: Hey @Hendrix could you please elaborate the paper what does it mean.

Comment: @ShadabSayeed:  Hendrix' link tabulates the values of your sum.  For $n=3$ you have nine entries.  Reading them by rows they are $1,2,3,2,2,6,3,6,3$ which sum to $28$ as shown.  The last part under FORMULA is exactly what your question asks.

Comment: @RossMillikan But the formula then further link to some another paper. I am unable to clearly understand what it means.

Comment: A related question: [How do we efficiently compute the value of expression given below?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3443535)

Answer (score 1):

The only simplification I can see is to write your formula as 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)}=\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \operatorname{lcm}(i,j)$$
To see that $\frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)}=\operatorname{lcm}(i,j)$, consider the factors of some prime that divides $i$ or $j$.  $\gcd(i,j)$ includes the minimum power of that prime between $i$ and $j$.  $\operatorname{lcm}(i,j)$ contains the maximum power of that prime between $i$ and $j$, so their product has the same power as $ij$ does.

The double sum just says take all possible pairs of $i,j$, evaluate $\operatorname{lcm}(i,j)$ and add them up.  If $n=3$ each of $i,j$ ranges from $1$ to $3$ and you have $9$ terms to add.  We can put the terms in an array with $i$ being the row and $j$ being the column (but it is symmetric here) and they are
$$\begin {array} {r r r}1&2&3\\2&2&6\\3&6&3 \end{array}$$

Adding all these numbers gives $28$, which is the third entry in the linked sequence.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)^2} 
&= \sum_{d = 1} ^ n \sum_{\gcd(i,j) = d} \frac{(i * j)}{d^2} \\
&= \sum_{d = 1} ^ n \sum_{\gcd(i,j) = 1} ^ {1 \leq i,j \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{d} \rfloor} ij 
\end{align}
$$
so we may first compute $f(n) = \sum\limits_{\gcd(i,j) = 1} ^ {1 \leq i,j \leq n} ij = \sum\limits_{l=1} ^n \mu(l) \sum\limits_{l|i} i \sum\limits_{l|j} j =\sum\limits_{l=1} ^n \mu(l)l^2 (\lfloor \frac{n}{l} \rfloor)^2 (\lfloor \frac{n}{l} \rfloor + 1)^2  $, where $mu$ is Mobius function.
and
$$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)^2} = \sum\limits_{d = 1}^n f(\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \rfloor )
$$

### Oh no, you want compute $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)^2}$ but not $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \frac{(i * j)}{\gcd(i,j)}$, so the answer blow is not right.

It is easy to see $\sum_{\gcd(i,n)= 1} i = \frac{n \psi(n)}{2} $, where $\psi(n)$ is Euler's  totient function.

let us consider $\sum_{i=1} ^n lcm(i,n)$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1} ^n lcm(i,n) 
&= \sum_{i=1} ^n \frac{i \cdot n}{\gcd(i,n)} \\
&= n \sum_{d|n} \sum_{\gcd(i,\frac{n}{d})= 1} i \\
&= \frac{n}{2} \sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d} \psi(\frac{n}{d}) \\
&= \frac{n}{2} \sum_{d|n} d \psi(d)
\end{align}
$$

so
$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n lcm(i,j)
&= 2 \sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n} ^ n lcm(i,j) - \sum_{i=1} ^n i \\
&= \sum_{i = 1} ^n i \sum_{d|i} d \psi(d) - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
&= \sum_{d = 1} ^n d \psi(d) \sum_{d|i} i - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
&= \frac{ \sum_{d = 1} ^n d \psi(d)  \lfloor \frac{n}{d} \rfloor (\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \rfloor + 1) - n(n+1)}{2} \\
\end{align}
$$